# How to open a file with similar name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, wildcard

I'm trying to open files in a folder with VBA under the condition that their names are similar to the names of other files, which in turn will also be opened.

With the following code I'm opening files with names "1_FirmA_v1.0", "1_FrimB_v1.0",.... from folder1 and afterwards I'm executing some commands on those files.

My problem is that I want to open files from folder2 whenever their names are similar to the name of the file from folder1 that is openend in the loop. The names of the files in folder2 are "2_FirmA_v1.1", "2_FirmB_v1.5",... . So when I open "1_FirmA_v1.0" from folder1 I want to open "2_FirmA_v1.1" from folder2.The problem is that I don't know how to put the code in a way that it searchs dynamically for the name of the file of the 2nd folder as it is not clear which exact name the file has. This is what I tried so far:

```
Sub Makro1()

Dim x As Workbook
Dim y As Workbook
Dim myPath, fname

myPath = "C:\Desktop\"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\TEST\")

fname = Dir(fldr & "\1*")
'fname2 = myPath2 & "Daten" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 12, Len(fname) - 25) & "v2.1test.xlsx"
'fname3 = myPath3 & "Daten" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 12, Len(fname) - 25) & "v2.0.xlsx"

Do While fname <> ""


Set x = Workbooks.Open(fldr & fname)
Set y = Workbooks.Open(myPath & "2" & Mid(fname, Len(fname) - 31, Len(fname) - 25) & "v*")

x.Activate
fname = Dir
Loop
```

Unfortuneatly it seems that I cannot use the "*" in the command workbooks.open. Does anybody know another way of handling this?
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

OK, I'll start an answer and we will see how we go.

Firstly, just because it's better in many ways, set a reference to `Windows.Scripting` then declare your `fso` as

```
Dim fso as Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
```

as this will give you the intelliSense and make things easier.

In terms of your wildcard, you need to narrow it down.  Let's assume that we are looking for the string between the underscores, in this case "FirmA".  You will need to look through the files in the folder until you find this.

```
Dim fldr as Scripting.Folder 'again, gives you the intelliSense
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder("C:\TEST\")
Dim fi as Scripting.File
For Each fi in fldr.Files
    If fi.Name Like "*FirmA*" Then '(hardcoded, but you will replace)
        <your code>
    End if
Next
```

How you extract "FirmA" is trickier.  You will need to give more background on what the file names look like.  There needs to be *some* form of pattern for this to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! The fiile names of the files in folder 1 look like: 'Data_FirmA_v1.0' (the file names just differ on the name of the firm).
The names in the other folder which should be opened under the condition that they are similar to the opened one in folder 1 look like: 'Rating_FirmA_v1.x' (the file names are not necessarily of the same version, so even if 'Data_FirmA_v1.0' the other file I want to open might be 'Rating_FirmA_v1.1' or another version)

Comment: That should give you enough to work it out.  The one thing to watch out for is temporary Excel files; you might want to filter out any file names with a tilde `~` as these will cause problems.