# Why are some files with space and hyphen in name returned as Nothing?

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code to open xlsx files, where I know only part of the name.

For example, the file I want to open is “English test(1-36).xlsx”, and the end numbers, i.e. (1-36) may change in the future.

I have used these solutions.

```vb
arra = Array("Finance test", "English test", "Finance test", "Product Development test", "Consumer Services test", "CSR test", "ITGT", "Information Security", "TU CIBIL Strategy", "CIBIL History and Evolution")

Set y = Workbooks.Open(folderNamey & "compilation.xlsm")

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Clear

y.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:L1").Value = headings

For Each x1 In arra
    MsgBox x1
    fname = Dir(folderName & "Assessment - Functional Induction - " & x1 & "*")
    MsgBox fname
    If fname <> "" Then
        fn = fn + 1
        Set x = Workbooks.Open(folderName & fname)
        MsgBox TypeName(x)
    End If
Next x1
```

I also tried these solutions.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71509889/vba-opening-a-file-with-partial-name](https://stackoverflow.com)

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57198720/how-to-open-a-file-with-similar-name-in-vba](https://stackoverflow.com)

These work for 9 out of 11 files. In two files, they are not able to open the files. The files are of the same format, with no errors. In every method, it is the same two files.

I used MsgBox to check the type, and instead of workbook, the last two files are showing Nothing.

---

There is also another type of “space” character known as a non-breaking space that is represented by the ASCII code number 160. It looks the same and could be causing the confusion. The dash is another one like that - there are 2 kinds and MSWord will use a different one. – braX

I renamed the files and typed out the same name and it worked. –
Ritam Chakrabarty

Comment: What are the names of the files that do not open?

Comment: Do you get a specific error message when it fails? We'll assume "not able to open" means that you get an error on the `Set x =` line?

Comment: @kevin last two files on the arraylist; "TU CIBIL Strategy" and "CIBIL History and Evolution"

Comment: @braX No message. The code runs perfectly without opening those two files. I have mentioned the file names in the above comment.

Comment: Where is the MsgBox code showing the Type test you did? It does not seem to be part of your question.

Comment: Regardless of your "nothing" test, the "bad" files open with no errors? Your variable is just not getting set to what you expect?

Comment: I meant what are the names of the excel files that you are expecting to open? Maybe the names in your array are correct, but maybe the name of the actual file is incorrect, has an extra space or something.

When your code hits the MsgBox fname line, do you get a blank message box pop up? That would indicate the Dir function did not find any filename that matches your criteria.

Comment: Are you using `On Error Resume Next` in your code? If so, remove it and then try.

Comment: @braX I didn't post it in the code. But I wrote it after x. In the actual code, there are some row operations on x that I have not posted here.

Comment: @kevin Yeah I am getting a blank message box. But the names seem to be correct. I even renamed the files and tried and still those two files are not opening.

Comment: @braX No. Not using On Error Resume Next

Comment: Maybe add the code you used for the Type test, instead of just telling us where you put it.

Comment: @braX  Ok. Added it. Below the set x line

Comment: Is it possible that `folderName & fname` is more than 260 characters? Is the path variable really really long? You can also try a `FileSystemObject` instead of `Dir`. But as kevin similarly said, 9 times out of 10 it's just that the filename does not match, even after you are sure you checked it. Make a test routine that does nothing but open one of the problem files... hard coded, that way you isolate the problem. Then copy/paste the exact filename from explorer into the code instead of using your array.

Comment: There is also another type of “space” character known as a non-breaking space that is represented by the ASCII code number 160. It looks the same and could be causing the confusion. The dash is another one like that - there are 2 kinds and MSWord will use a different one. I'm running out of guesses.

Comment: @braX Oh my god, it worked. I renamed the files and typed out the same name and it worked. Thank you.

Comment: @kevin I renamed the files and typed out the same name and it worked.